# how to judge sql performance through these 2 explain?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I give you 2 explain results from MySQL,how do you know which query is better?

the first sql explain

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sbtest2
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 700100
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the second sql explain

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 100
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: a
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: b.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: sbtest2
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 700100
        Extra: Using index
3 rows in set (1.46 sec)
```

I think I will choose the first query because there are "a lot of" things to do in the second explain,but actually the second query is much faster than the first query , so my question is if I don't see the response time,how to judge their performance through explain ?

the first query's Duration: 4.43704325

```
select * from sbtest.sbtest2 
order by id 
limit 700000,100;
```

after restart MySQL server to clean cache ,the second query's uration: 2.08889400 (faster)

```
select * from sbtest.sbtest2 a
inner join 
(select id from sbtest.sbtest2  order by id limit 700000,100 ) as b
on a.id=b.id;
```

can anybody help me ?

Comment: i think you execute the 1st query and get stat then execute the second one and got stat

Comment: if that correct in second query you got better performance due to mysql query cashing not its real performance :)

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka  sorry~ can you explain how to get stat ?

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka I have already restart MySQL server